# AWS Firewall allow traffic from EKS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I have an EKS Cluster, and a separate Database server running on a EC2 instance,
I am using aws's security groups as my firewall to allow only specific servers access to my db,I am trying to figure out how to allow my cluster to communicate with it, without adding allowing the whole internet access the database?

Answer (score 0):

I can't possibly write down the exact procedure how you would need to configure it here but the answer to your question is `Security groups for pods`. It is documented in this [workshop](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/115_sg-per-pod/) and in this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-security-groups-for-pods/)